# How to map Nothing to Elm Json.Decoder?

Tags: json, elm

This is a question for Elm v0.18

I have

```
type alias Header =
    { value : String
    , term : Maybe String
    }
```

And I need to populate it with a `Json.Decode Decoder`. However only `value` exists in JSON, and for `term` I need to assign `Nothing`.

I am able to build a decoder in a hackish way by using `Json.Decode.maybe` together with non-existent field:

```
import Json.Decode exposing (map2, field, string, maybe)

map2 Header (field "header" string)
  (maybe (field "no_such_field" string))
```

What is a "proper" way to generate a `Decoder` with `Nothing` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Json.Decode.succeed`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Json-Decode#succeed) can be used to wrap a constant value in a decoder:

```elm
map2 Header (field "header" string)
    (succeed Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to just use an anonymous function that only takes one argument, the "header", and always fills in `Nothing` for the term:

```
map (\header -> Header header Nothing) (field "header" string)
```

or equivalently

```
map (\header -> { value = header, term = Nothing }) (field "header" string)
```